# Command not found sqlite3

Tags: sqlite

I beginner, and I try to join a database like this:

```
[root@synapse ~]# sqlite3 homeserver.db "pragma busy_timeout=20000; SELECT room_id FROM rooms"
```

However, that puts me in error:

```
-bash: sqlite3 : commande introuvable
```

Is there a way to use psql and not sqlite?

Comment: You should install sqlite. If you are using linux, there's probably a package you can install  with running either `apt-get install sqlite3` or `yum install sqlite`

Comment: @nos
When I tried the first one : `[root@synapse ~]# sudo apt-get install sqlite3
`, it puts me this error : `sudo: apt-get : commande introuvable`

Comment: Then you need to tell us which linux distro you are using, or you need to read the documentation for your linux distro on how you can install additional packages, and then find the package that constains sqlite.

Comment: You may be able to google `how to install apt-get in [your distribution name]`, then retry the command. Here's the answer for one popular distribution:

https://askubuntu.com/questions/860375/installing-apt-get

Comment: @BrianDewhirst Not every Linux system is Ubuntu...

Comment: @Murphy I agree 100%, it was just my best guess based on the experience of the user and the size of the Debian-derived Linux footprint. They should modify the google search to include whatever distro they're using.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there a way to use psql and not sqlite?

No. **If** it is a SQLite database then you need to use the SQLite CLI. Is it?

> `sqlite3 : commande introuvable`

Find out how to install the software packages on your distribution, then install the `sqlite3` package, and you should be fine.

As `apt-get` isn't already installed, chances are you're not using any Ubuntu variant; if you add the name of the distribution you're using to your question you may get more specific help.